# Documents are not selectable in SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-library

I have a Document Library which works fine when I'm in the actual Library, but when I am in a modified or created view, I lose the ability to click on the document.

What I'm seeing is one view ends with: ".../library"
The one where I'm experiencing issues ends with: ".../library/Company%20Library"

So obviously I have "Company Library" somewhere, but I a) can't figure out how to edit this out to remove the *space* and b) I can not figure out why this view precludes me from the ability to select documents. Please help!

I have full admin privileges, if that helps.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say click on the document, do you mean selecting the row, clicking the name of the document to open it, or clicking the icon to open the document?  You can edit the URL of your view by going to List Settings, clicking the view, and changing the web address.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, in the below view, I can click the document (hyperlinked to the Document Library, pulls up the document in the browser)
".../library"

When I'm in this view (below), the cursor stays as an arrow and I do *not* have the option to select the document. I can check it out or modify the view...just everything but actually viewing the document (i.e. not hyperlinked).

Comment: It might help us if you add a screenshot of your library and a screenshot of your custom view's column settings

Comment: Unfortunately, that's *not an option given the system I'm working on; on a different network, if I can kind of talk around it.

*Corrected grammar

Comment: Understood. Go into the settings for each view. Tell me what columns are selected in each view. Let's call them view1 (working) and view2 (not working). For example, Name linked to document, or Name linked to document and edit library, etc.

Comment: So the view that works (View 1) is based off the documents on the Home page of the subsite.

The view that does NOT work (View 2) is the actual Document Library.

I have multiple columns, and they mirror each other, for each view (Name, Title, Category, Subcategory, etc.). Some are custom columns and there's no issues with the columns. Is it possible that SharePoint has an issue with the %20 in between my title "Company%20Library"--how do I find that directory to change it? It's not showing up in Library Settings.

Comment: Well that's very strange, that the document library itself is the one not working. The reason there's a %20 is because you (or the creator) named the library "Company Library." There's no way to change that at this point, SharePoint shouldn't care about the space. Try creating a brand new view in the library with the document name as the only column. See if you can open the document from there.

Comment: I did as you suggested and still no dice--"Name" was the only column I kept and it shows me all the files, but they are *NOT* selectable. I realize this is much harder to diagnose without pictures, but let me say that I really do appreciate everyone's help with this!

Comment: Is the default view your only view on that library? Do you have other libraries that are working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing a column in the view that allows the selection box.  Also, the url for a view is set at the time of creation.  It would be best to recreate a view with the name "CompanyLibrary" and delete the old one.  You could even use the old one as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the view, or create a new view, and ensure that the column "Name (linked to document with edit menu)" is visible in the view. See screenshot below. [image: screenshot]

Comment: This is the first thing we checked, if you take the time to read the string of comments above.

Comment: In the comments it was said to create a view with keeping the document name as the only column, To be able to view the document from the link in the view, you must have the "Name(linked to document with edit menu)" - that will provide the ellipsis with the popout menu, or "Name(linked to document)" will simply provide the name with hyperlink for viewing.

Comment: The columns in the view that is working are identical to the columns in the view that are not. That's why I didn't pursue having him clarify even though he didn't answer my question directly. Since it's the hyperlink that's not working, not the edit menu, this is irrelevant.

Comment: Well as mentioned in the comments it is very challenging to determine the problem without more information or screenshots. The only way I know of to control the hyperlink on the view is by ensuring that one of those 2 columns is visible, so I believe it is perfectly relevant. If it does not solve the problem in this case, then it should not be marked as the answer, but it is still relevant for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something was fundamentally wrong with this library so I just bit the bullet and deleted it. I re-added it and now it seems to be working. No idea what was wrong with it, but I sincerely appreciate all your guys' help! Thank  you!